# Show that a collection of subsets of a set is a topology or not.

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I know that its a topology for Ex 2.6, but I dont know how to explain it. I know that T is a topology on a collection of subsets of X if it satisfies the axioms: 1. null set belong to T, and X belong to T.
2. If say U is a sub-collection of T, then the union of U should belong to T, and the same concept or theory applies for a finite sub collection of T.

Can someone help me on this, any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: For 2.8 maybe read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/307834/4280) first to get ideas? or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1486508/4280)?

Comment: Ex.2.6 very easy to explain, just identify the three conditions, first, $\varnothing,X\in\mathcal{T}$. Then, try all possible union and intersection of elements of $\mathcal{T}$ and you'll know that the condition 2 and 3 are both satisfied. And you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for 2.6;

1. $\phi$ and $X$ are in $\tau$
2. Union of any  members of $\tau$ is again in $\tau.$\ (check!)
3. Intersection of any   members of $\tau$ is again in $\tau.$ (check!)

Hence $\tau $ is a topology on $X.$ 
Follow the same arguments for other two problems as well!